# UITableCell Reusing itself

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I made a `UITableViewCell` and I have 20 rows in that table in which 5 at a time on screen.
I have set accessory view checkd mark in didSelect delegate method on which row is being selected. My concern is let suppose first row is selected and its accessory type is checked, now if i scroll the table we see the sixth one is also checked. I know that the cell is reusing itself and not creating itself again.

Comment: Just try my method,it will work fine.I had met with this kind of problem many times.

Comment: thanks Dzy... I will try to make it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model should be able to handle which cell is checked and which is not. To simplify the problem, you can keep an array which will the `NSIndexPath`s that should be checked. If only one can be checked at the time, an ivar of the type `NSIndexPath` is more than enough.

---

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
            // Ok this one is selected, so we will remove it from the Reference Array.

    }
    else
    {
        // Ok this one doesn't has a checkMark
        // First add the checkmark
        [[aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

        // Add the NSIndexPath to the Array of references
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jacky for your update..
but the requirement is we have more than one cell can be selected at a time ...
abhishek

Comment: As Jacky said, keep an array of indexPaths or even better add a property to your model. In that way you can have multiple checked

Comment: Check my Edit. In this case, I would probably keep an NSDictionary with the keys as the NSIndexPath and the value as for example the row wrapped on a NSNumber (the value is not important). The important part is the key, because it's faster to just: `[myDictionary objectForKey:indexPath]` than enumerating a `NSArray`

Comment: Jacky what is the role of that array...?

Comment: The array will keep a reference to the `NSIndexPath` of the cells that should checked when you enter on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. But again, a NSMutableDictionary might be a better solution since it's faster.

Answer (score -1):

In the delegate method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId ];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                       reuseIdentifier:cellId ] autorelease];
    }
}
```

Set different cell ID to different cell row.

Comment: Just try my method,it will work fine.I had met with this kind of  problem many times.

Comment: This is really bad design, if you create a cellId for each individual cell you will consume memory. Answer of Jacky Boy is the way to go

Comment: It will not consume so much memory.As the Apple Document said,the rows that hide from the screen will be released auto.When the rows show again,it will be reloaded.There only five rows you can see on the screen,so there are four more cell ID string be saved to specify different cell rows.And I think it is more efficiently than Jacky Boy's way.On that way, the table must search the dictionary which row is checked every and every time,so that it will consume more memory.